# Completing inductive step of proof of Cochran's theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

On slides 23-26 [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~fwood/Teaching/w4315/Fall2009/lecture_cochran.pdf), they prove the case for $k=2$ of Cochran's theorem. I don't see why you can use induction to prove it for general $k$.

In more detail, they already prove the following:

> If $$ Q = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = x'A_1 x + x'A_2 x = Q_1 + Q_2 $$ where
>   $A_1$ and $A_2$ are PSD with ranks $r_1, r_2$ such that $r_1+r_2=n$,
>   then there exists an orthogonal matrix $C$ such that, with $x=Cy$,
>
> $$ Q_1 = y_1^2 + \cdots + y_{r_1}^2, \\ Q_2 = y_{r_1+1}^2 + \cdots + y_n^2. $$

I don't see how to use this to show it's true for general $k$ not just $k=2$ as above by induction.

If you split $Q_2$ into $Q_{21}+Q_{22}$ where $Q_{21}$ and $Q_{22}$ have ranks $a$ and $b$ for example, then you'd have a **different** orthogonal matrix $C_1\neq C$ such that, for $\hat{x}=(x_{r_1+1},\ldots,x_n)$,

$\hat{x}=C_1 y$ and 
$$Q_{21}=y_{r_1}^2 + \cdots + y_{r_1+a-1}^2,\quad Q_{22}=y_{r_1+a}^2 + \cdots + y_{r_n}^2$$

I don't see how you can show from $k=2$ that this is true for general $k\geq 2$, i.e. that there exists an orthogonal matrix $C$ that simultaneously gets us $$Q_i = y^2_{r_1+\cdots+r_{i-1}+1} + \cdots + y^2_{r_1+\cdots+r_i}$$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$. Anyone know how to complete this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sup Y9,

Note that the assumption $r_1 + \cdots + r_n = n$ will be problematic if you try to set up the induction directly, since if you handle $A_1$ first, you are left with $r_2 + \cdots + r_n$ which is not equal to $n$. This suggests that the induction involves looking at a lower-dimensional problem, i.e. the "new $n$" when you apply the induction step after handling $A_1$ is $\tilde{n} = r_2 + \cdots + r_n$, as described below.

---

It might be easier to state the result as follows: if $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are PSD with ranks summing to $n$ satisfying $I = A_1 + \cdots + A_n$, then there exists an orthonormal basis $\{c_1, \ldots, c_n\}$ such that

- $A_1$ is the identity on the subspace $\text{span}\{c_1, \ldots, c_{r_1}\}$, and zero on the orthogonal complement,
- $A_2$ is the identity on the subspace $\text{span}\{c_{r_1 + 1}, \ldots, c_{r_1 + r_2}\}$, and zero on the orthogonal complement,
- and so on.

[Note that $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ here correspond to the columns of $C$ in the original formulation of the result.]

---

Using the $k=2$ result, we can handle the situation $I = A_1 + B$ where $B := A_2 + \cdots + A_n$.
This implies $A_2 + \cdots + A_n$ is the identity on the subspace $\operatorname{span}\{c_{r_1 + 1}, \ldots, c_n\}$, and zero on the orthogonal complement i.e. $\operatorname{span}\{c_1, \ldots, c_{r_1}\}$.

Since $\operatorname{rank}(A_2) + \cdots + \operatorname{rank}(A_n) = r_2 + \cdots + r_n = n - r_1 = \operatorname{rank}(A_2 + \cdots + A_n)$, each individual $A_i$ must also be zero on $\operatorname{span}\{c_1, \ldots, c_{r_1}\}$.

So we can restrict our attention to this $(n-r_1)$-dimensional subspace $\operatorname{span}\{c_{r_1 + 1}, \ldots, c_n\}$,  and we have another instance of the theorem's conditions, since the sum of $A_2, \ldots, A_n$ is the identity, and the sum of their ranks is the dimension of the space ($n - r_1$). By induction, we may apply the theorem to this smaller problem and obtain the result.

---

It is possible to translate the above proof into strictly matrix notation if you wish. The gist of it is that you can modify certain subsets of columns of $C$ at a time without messing up previous steps.

When you make lots of money from your cushy job, please remember us.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah hoping to land a postdoc somewhere first but if that doesn’t work out...welp.

Comment: Why is it that $\operatorname{rank}(A_2) + \cdots + \operatorname{rank}(A_n) = r_2 + \cdots + r_n = n - r_1 = \operatorname{rank}(A_2 + \cdots + A_n)$ implies each individual $A_i$ must also be zero on $\operatorname{span}\{c_1, \ldots, c_{r_1}\}$?

Comment: @Glassjawed $\text{colspace}(A_2 + \cdots +A _n) \subseteq \text{colspace}(A_2) + \cdots + \text{colspace}(A_n)$ always holds in general. The rank condition further implies equality of these subspaces. Then $\text{colspace}(A_i) \subseteq \text{colspace}(A_2 + \cdots + A_n)$.